# "Login timeout expired/Not enough information to log on" error

Tags: odbc, stata, teradata

I am running a loop in Stata (a statistics package) that pulls in a series of datasets from a Teradata DB via ODBC on an Ubuntu server. I am getting the following error (in Stata):

```
Login timeout expired
SQLSTATE=HYT00
[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Not enough information to log on
SQLSTATE=28000
```

Is that controlled by the `LoginTimeout=10` in my .odbc.ini file or is there some other setting that I need to adjust?

I have tried changing that, but the error tends to happen in the middle of the night, so I can't tell if that fixed it.

Here is what the DSN entry in my .odbc.ini file look like:

```
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_64/lib/tdata.so
Description=AAAA
DBCName=BBBB
Username=CCC
Password=DDDD
DefaultDatabase=access_views
MaxRespSize=32000
LoginTimeout=100000000
SessionMode=Teradata
Connection=GLOBAL
```

Comment: What are the connection parameters being provided? We need more details to help triage the problem and offer suggestions.

Comment: Are these the parameters you had in mind?

Comment: can you check if you have registered an entry under the entry    
[ODBC Data Sources]  
dsn_name=tdata.so

Comment: @mig-25foxbat I have one for each DSN that I use.